# My wordpress website loading to much slow

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So I recently setup a Wordpress site that is being hosted through HostGator with their business share-hosting plan. The website was experiencing very slow load times, sometimes up to 30-45 seconds … too. Loading the site in its current state still feels pretty slow and after taking these measures, I'm unsure of what could be causing the issue, or if possibly the host might be too slow

[image: GtMetrix Noted]

www.earthnews24.com

Comment: There are several possible reasons for this. If you haven't implemented a Caching plugin, you can try that.

Comment: Hello Juan. I have also in my site Caching plugin but after that site also running slow.

Answer (score 0):

your site have lots of contents so its better to move to cdn with dedicated server and use wpfastest cache to cache your all pages.